# Unable to access localhost when running Cypress GitHub Action

Tags: angular, cypress, github-actions

I'm unable to run the Cypress GitHub Action by just following their [README](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/cypress-io) instructions. According to the GitHub Action logs the Angular WebApp starts normally, but somehow the Cypress testing framework doesn't find it when trying to access it. Also everything works fine locally, using the same config / tests.

**Cypress config:**

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

**Start script:**
`"start": "ng version && ng serve --disable-host-check",`

**GitHub Action (just the jobs part):**

```
jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '16.15'
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
        with:
          start: npm run start
          browser: chrome
          wait-on: 'http://localhost:4200'
```

**What I tried to so far:**

- Running it without extra Node Setup (which defaults to 18 and apparently has some issues)
- Trying localhost alternative likes `127.0.0.1` and `::1`
- Trying it without `wait-on` (which just leads to 'We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.' and ESOCKETTIMEDOUT error). With the wait-on it just times out before running the tests
- Trying another port, like `4300`
- Trying latest ubuntu version
- Adding screenshot saving, on which it just shows an error page with: Sorry, we could not load: http://localhost:4200/en/
- Running the start script with --verbose, which confirms me, that it really runs on `http://localhost:4200`

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Most probably, the server needs to run in the background as not to block the tests i.e. `ng serve --disable-host-check &`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried that, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

2 changes in the Cypress run step made it work for me:

1. Change `wait-on: 'http://localhost:4200'` to `wait-on: 'http://localhost:4200/en'` because we use a localised baseHref
2. Increase the waiting time by adding `wait-on-timeout: 180`. Don't be fooled by your local start time (as it is just 30 seconds for me).

Kudos to Mike McCready from the Cypress team to help me fix this issue :)